# php сложение времени

Tags: php, дата, datetime

Подскажите, как правильно складывать значения времени? Время получаю в формате `04:00`, перевожу его в таймстамп, затем делаю сложение. Но результат оставляет желать лучшего - вместо `08:00` получаю `05:00`. Собственно вот код:

```
$th2 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')."04:00");
$th3 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')."04:00");
print_r(date("h-i", $th2+$th3));
```

Comment: не могу понять вот эту логику `$th2+$th3`, Вы знаете что такое unix time? Знаете что возвращает вам функция `strtotime`? Давайте подробно скажите зачем Вам нужно так делать и может сможем помочь Вам.

Comment: складывание двух timestamp немного лишено смысла. Вычитание - да, смысл есть. складывать можно две дельты, можно метку времени и дельту.

Comment: вам нужен http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.add.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хотя работа с встроенным классом **[DateTime](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php)** более гибкая и удобная.

Решение:

```
$date = strtotime('04:00') + strtotime('04:00') - strtotime("00:00:00");
echo date('H:i',$date);
```

Comment: `более гибкая и удобная`. А помоему нет - так проще и понятнее, и без лишних переменных.

Answer (score 0):

Можно к некоторой полуночи прибавлять временные интервалы:

```
$d = new DateTime("00:00");
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i')."\n";

$interval1 = new DateInterval("PT4H");
$interval2 = new DateInterval("PT5H");
// Альтернативный формат:
// $interval1 = DateInterval::createFromDateString("4 hours + 0 min");
// $interval2 = DateInterval::createFromDateString("5 hours + 0 min");    
$d->add($interval1);
$d->add($interval2);

echo $d->format('H:i')."\n";
```

Вывод:

> ```
> 2017-05-30 00:00:00
> 09:00
> ```

Можно пойти чуть дальше и вычитать оригинальную дату, чтобы получить только сумму интервалов:

```
$d = new DateTime("00:00");
$save = clone $d;

$interval1 = DateInterval::createFromDateString("14 hours + 20 min");
$interval2 = DateInterval::createFromDateString("15 hours + 0 min");

$d->add($interval1);
$d->add($interval2);

echo $save->diff($d)->format('%a д. %H:%I')."\n";
```

Вывод:

> ```
> 1 д. 05:20
> ```